# Display a Toast when a button is clicked frequently

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development so excuse me for this question.

So I have a button that when clicked, it will call a method called `btnDelay(btnName)`.

Inside that method is this line of codes:

```
private void btnDelay(final Button btn){
    btn.setEnabled(false);

    /*if (counter == 0){
        counter++;
    }*/

    Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
    buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

That will disable the button for **5 seconds**.

Now what I want to do is when the user clicks the button again and the 5 seconds is not finished, will display a Toast stating that the user's action is too frequent.

Is there a way I can do this? I am thinking of using a counter that will count how many times the user clicked that specific button and will reset to 0 after the 5 seconds on the TimerTask is done. But is there a simplier way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: That method won't be called, because a disabled button cannot listen to events.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Oh! I missed that tiny detail. Thank you for clarifying. So what's the better/best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your button won't fire an `onClick` event if it's disabled. So instead of disabling it, set the colours to grey or something so it *looks* disabled and then in your `onClick` handler for the button:

```
if(enabled){
  btnDelay();
} 
else {
  sendAToast();
}
```

Then in `btnDelay()`, set `enabled = false` (and set the colours to grey if you want), and inside `run()` set `enabled = true`. 
Also don't forget to `private boolean enabled = true` at the top of your class :)

Comment: Yes. I am very sorry for missing that very tiny detail. Thank you for mentioning and clarifying my mistakes. Sure will not miss that again in the future ;) by the way, I will try this approach. Thank you!

Comment: Working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a Boolean variable for button state. Because if you write `btn.setEnabled(false);`   ,`buttonClickEvent` can not be triggered for five seconds.

```
boolean btnState = true;
private void btnDelay(final Button btn){
    if (btnState){
        Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
        buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btnState = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "your_message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as Mike Speed's answer but much simplier.